# Reaction of nitrobenzene with potassium ferricyanide

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds

I came across this question in an exercise book. Can anyone give detailed answer (mechanism) of this reaction?

[image]

I am unable to proceed. I thought there maybe some redox reaction involved where $$\ce{Fe^3+ -> Fe^2+}$$ maybe taking place but then nitrobenzene would have to be oxidised. Can someone please help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go more for an oxidation, but on the ring (hydroxylation). 
My guess comes from this paper here : ["The Hydroxylation of Aromatic Nitro Compounds by Alkalies" by O. C. Dermer](http://ojs.library.okstate.edu/osu/index.php/OAS/article/view/5955/5577).

This is very harsh (and somehow old) chemistry.

First, for *m*-dinitrobenzene and *sym*-trinitrobenzene, hydroxylation is reported in your conditions, that is to say alcaline conditions with the help of potassium ferricyanide as oxidizing agent (reactions A and B, see reference in the paper).

Second, the authors report the reaction C (with less than 4% yield though, according to my calculations), with a small amount of *p*-hydroxyazobenzene as a side-product. They did this reaction by mixing only nitrobenzene with potassium hydroxide, so I would expect the same product (*o*-nitrophenol) with maybe a better yield in your conditions.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, since there are no electrophiles that are formed, the only reaction that comes to mind is nucleophilic aromatic substitution.

$\ce{NaOH}$ does a displacement reaction with $\ce{K3Fe(CN)6}$, yielding the $\ce{CN-}$ ion.

The cyanide ion attacks the benzene ring, giving three possible resonance structures:

[image]

The hydrogen attached to the carbon with the cyanide ion is accepted by the strong base $\ce{NaOH}$.

Next, the nitrile undergoes acid-catalysed hydrolysis to form a carboxylic acid:

[image]

Comment: I thought it was tough to remove ligands inside a complex. Can you explain how/why CN- comes out?

Comment: Btw, you left your mechanism at amide, no need to edit it to acid though. I know the mechanism

Comment: While $\ce{CN-}$ is possible to be displaced by $\ce{OH-}$, it is a much stronger ligand. Therefore I suspect that this reaction would not happen to a large extent. What's more, nucleophilic aromatic substitution generally occurs with  aryl halides since $\ce{X-}$ is a much better leaving group.

Comment: I've edited the mechanism above already, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I'm afraid there are some real problems with this loss of a hydride. If CN- attacks nitrobenzene, the subsequent step must expel H- not H+. Do you have any reference for this reaction? Nucleophilic substitution of hydrides is not unknown (Chichibabin reaction), but it doesn't make much sense here. cc @AlphaRomeo

Comment: Aside from that there are some errors in the mechanisms. In the first mechanism, the first arrow should be a forward arrow $\to$ not a resonance arrow $\leftrightarrow$. The third structure is missing a double bond between C and N. In the second mechanism, the amide has to be protonated first before H2O can attack, and NH2 has to be protonated before it can leave.

Comment: @orthocresol Yes, I don't think this reaction is likely to happen in great amount as I've noted. But there's no possible electrophile to undergo electrophilic substitution either. However, it seems unfair to simply put "No reaction". And I've skimped on the amide part. :P Thanks for pointing that out though.

Comment: @orthocresol My exercise book is the only place where I saw this reaction. Unfortunately I dont know the answer to the question. There is a good possibility that the author just made this reaction up, as it wont be the first time this has happened. ( not mentioning the book and author as its a local book for exam preparation, most probably you wont be able to find it on net)

Comment: I think H attached to the carbon which bonds to cyanide group is a $H^-$, which is a base (and even stronger than NaOH), so how can it be taken away?